# Picking commit objects in Git

Tags: git, github

How do pick only one commit from a branch on a remote repository and merge it to the current branch on my local repository?

I looked around on google, and I found git cherry-pick. But this seems to be for doing this only across branches in the same repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fetch the other repo:

```
git fetch http://github.com/otherguy/forkedproject.git
```

That downloads all the history from that repo, but without changing `HEAD` or your staging area.

Then, `cherry-pick` the commit.

Comment: Note that unlike `clone`, `fetch` will pull only one branch head, by default "master".  If your commit is on a different branch, you'll need to specify that as the final argument to fetch.

Comment: @AndyRoss: not exactly. In my Git 1.7.6 at least, `fetch` will retrieve all branches on the remote.