# Multiple codebases using DVCS, copy a feature?

Tags: git, dvcs

I haven't tried it but i think its easier then I expect.

I'm making a project with two codebases. My own with all the advance features and a public one with less features (one that only uses freely available software thus may have less features). Now of course I have a dev or feature branch so when its stable i'll put it into my main codebase.

My question is if someone else adds a feature to the limited codebase how might I pull it into my main codebase? Lets assume his dev branch is private and i only have access to his branch after its been merged with the limited codebase. I cant pull the codebase because they would be conflicts. What do I do? Is there a non weird way to diff the changes and apply it to my full featured codebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the history are very different, cherry-picking the right commit(s) seems the simplest solution.
See:

- "[Git cherry-pick syntax and merge branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626754/git-cherry-pick-syntax-and-merge-branches)"
- "[Picking commit objects in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679017/picking-commit-objects-in-git)" (fetch + cherry-pick)